# Solve $y’ = 1 + y^2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let:

$$y’ = 1 + y^2 \\ y(0) = 0 $$

We need to find a maximal interval $(a,b)$ so that the problem with the initial conditions, has a solution.

Therefore, I think I need to find a solution, there I can look at the validity interval.

Yet, I don’t have even a direction how to solve this equation. It’s a non linear equation. Not separate, can’t use integration constant, not Bernoulli form, don’t see how substitution can help me...

If I could guess I would say it something of the direction:

$$\text{d}y = (1+y^2) \text{d}x $$

But $y$ Is a function of $x$ So I can't just take the integral of both sides...

Can someone give me a hint?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you say it's not "separate"?

Comment: The solution is $\tan x$ and the maximal interval is $(-\frac {\pi} 2, \frac {\pi} 2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clearly a variable separable DE.

**Hint:** Rewrite it as $$\frac{\text{d}y}{1+y^2}=\text{d}x$$

Now, integrate both sides.

Answer (score 0):

As $x$ does not appear explicitly (the equation is autonomous), we can solve for $x(y)$ instead of $y(x)$, and that gives us

$$\frac1{x'(y)}=y^2+1$$ or

$$x'(y)=\dfrac1{1+y^2}$$ with the initial condition $x(0)=0.$

> $$x(y)=\arctan(y)\to y(x)=\tan(x).$$

Comment: How did you get to $x(y)$ can you explain? I’m having hard time with it

Comment: @Alon: it is just the inverse function.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\frac{dy}{dx}=1+y^2$$
Using the rule for the separation of variables, when we have a first order linear differential equation of the form $\frac{dy}{dx}=g(y)f(x)$ we can write
$$\int\frac{1}{g(y)}dy=\int f(x)dx$$
So in our case we can write
$$\int\frac{1}{1+y^2}dy=\int 1 dx$$
and the left hand side integral is $\arctan y$.